# Spread properties in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am trying to use the spread properties in my reducers, but it is coming back with an invalid syntax error. My build supports the use of the spread operator as I only get the error in my reducers.

auth_types.js

```
export const AUTH_USER = 'AUTH_USER'
export const UNAUTH_USER = 'UNAUTH_USER'
```

auth_actions.js

```
import { AUTH_USER, UNAUTH_USER } from './auth_types'



   export function signinUser({ email, password }) {
      return function(dispatch) {
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/signin`, { email, password })
          .then(response => {
            dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER })

            browserHistory.push('/feature')
          })
      }
    }
```

reducer.js

```
import { AUTH_USER, UNAUTH_USER } from '../actions/auth_types'

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case AUTH_USER:
      return { ...state, authenticated: true }
    case UNAUTH_USER:
      return { ...state, authenticated: false }
  }

  return state
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html):

> Since the object spread syntax is still a Stage 2 proposal for ECMAScript you’ll need to use a transpiler such as Babel to use it in production. You can use your existing es2015 preset, install [babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) and add it individually to the plugins array in your `.babelrc`.

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

> Note that this is still an experimental language feature proposal so it may change in the future.

Comment: That worked. Any reason why the syntax worked else where in my project though?

Comment: Nope :) No idea, sorry. Unless you were using the spread on an iterable like an array or string or map instead.

Comment: Ah, it was on an array. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack, you can fix this by enabling **stage-2** preset.

First install npm package:

```
npm install --save babel-preset-stage-2
```

Then add stage-2 to the presets array in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets:[ 'es2015', 'react', 'stage-2' ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```